# Rest Framework, problems in Post multiple objects

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I can't make a post on ProductQualityMonitor... I think it's something wrong with the list of QualityParameters.
When I try to make a post in the api view, in raw data, shows up ""detail": "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded".
And when I try to make a post using module "requests" in python:

```
insert= requests.post(database_url, data = json.dumps(new_entry),
                           headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

The code response is 200 instead of 201.

My models:

```
class ProductQualityMonitor(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(..)
    area = models.CharField(...))
    timeslot = models.DateTimeField(...)

    def get_measured_parameters(self):
         (...)

class QualityParameter(models.Model):
    PARAMETER_CHOICES = (
        (MEAN, MEAN),
        (MEDIAN, MEDIAN),
        (MAXIMUM, MAXIMUM),
        (MINIMUM, MINIMUM),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PARAMETER_CHOICES)
    value = models.FloatField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductQualityMonitor,
                            related_name="parameters")
```

My Serializers:

```
class QualityParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = QualityParameter
        fields = ("id","name", "value")


class ProductQualityMonitorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    parameters = QualityParameterSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductQualityMonitor
        fields = ("id","product_name", "area", "timeslot", "processing_line",
              "updated_on",'parameters')
```

My view:

```
class ProductQualityMonitorList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ProductQualityMonitor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductQualityMonitorSerializer
```

Comment: Rest framework doesn't support nested creation of objects. You will have to either override create method or make parameters as read only.

Comment: [See this doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Comment: with the create method I can post, thanks. But I need to post outside the shell. With Tastypie i used the python module "requests" and it works. Is it possible to do in rest framework?